# Cron Job PHP Foreach Only Sends Out ONE Email/Runs ONE Row

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a cron job that executes the following PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$freq = "1day";
$camp = $users->get_campaigns($freq);
foreach($camp as $val) {
    $data['customer'] = $val['thename']; 
    $data['companyname'] = $val['company']; 
    $data['email'] = $val['reply_to']; 
    if($val['defaultc'] == "1") {
        $phrase = $val['1'];
    }
    elseif($val['defaultc'] == "2") {
        $phrase = $val['2'];
    }
    elseif($val['defaultc'] == "3") {
        $phrase = $val['3'];
    }
    $placeholders = array("{customer}", "{companyname}", "{email}");
    $new_member_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $phrase);

    $headers = "From: ".$val['reply_to']."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$val['reply_to']."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }</style></head><body>";
    $message .= "".$new_member_file."</body></html>";

    mail($val['theemail'], $val['sub1'], $message, $headers,'-f'.$val['reply_to'].'');
    $users->email_sent($user_id);   
}
?>
```

If I access the file directly via my browser, it works **perfect**. However, if running it via a cron job, it will only execute the foreach code ONCE...meaning it only pulls the first row out of the MySQL database and sends ONE email, when it should be pulling multiple rows and sending multiple emails.

I have no clue why this is happening - I have tried searching for a reason why this is happening with no luck.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Does any of this (like the stuff in core/init.php or `get_campaigns()` make use of the `$_SERVER, $_GET, or $_POST` superglobals? Those would not be available via cron unless cron called the web server via something like wget. `$_SERVER` is easy to misuse in this context, if if it is used to get a hostname for example.

Comment: Also, make sure PHP is reporting errors and capture them with cron rather than sending them to /dev/null. Try it out yourself by executing it on the command line rather than the cron job or browser. Another common mistake with cron scripts relates to relative vs absolute file paths or assumptions about the `$PATH` available to the cron execution.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Good points, did not think of this - I'll take a look at my code. I'll update my code accordingly and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: you should post your own answer below to detail how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_campaigns() function in the script was using $_POST superglobals - cannot do this via cron jobs. Removed the $_POST superglobals and the cron script executed flawlessly.